# How to access JSON database using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

How can I find "firstname" with value "Anna" and display her "lastname" at the end using JavaScript? This is just a dummy example for me to understand how it works.

```js
var employees = [
    {
    "firstName":"John",
    "lastName":"Doe"
    }, 
    {
    "firstName":"Anna",
    "lastName":"Smith"
    },
    {
    "firstName":"Peter",
    "lastName":"Jones"
    }
];

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
employees.firstName;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to iterate and check for that value, then do what you want:

```
for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
    if (employees[i].firstName == "Anna") {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = employees[i].lastName;
        break;
    }
}
```

To display more than 1 Anna - I'd use `filter` on the array, and then `join`:

```
var lastNames = employees.filter(function(employee) {
    return employee.firstName == "Anna";
}).map(function(employee) {
    return employee.lastName;
}).join(",");

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = lastNames;
```

Comment: For some older browsers, you can not get an Object length. But if you had an Array instead of an Object i would suggest using this method. but loop backward instead of forward.

Comment: @RichardGrant -- This is an array - the above code never uses an object length. And why loop backwards instead of forwards?

Comment: Woops i didnt really look at the code to much your right. your code would work. i apologize. when you loop forward your loop needs to constantly keep checking the item length causing the loop to run much slower. there is plenty of documentation about this.

Comment: @RichardGrant -- Idk about much slower, the performance gain is extremely minimal - no need to optimize so soon.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. Just a final question, what if I have more then one "Anna", how can I display all of their "lastNames" in a row?

Answer (score 0):

```
var e = [
    {
    "firstName":"John",
    "lastName":"Doe"
    }, 
    {
    "firstName":"Anna",
    "lastName":"Smith"
    },
    {
    "firstName":"Peter",
    "lastName":"Jones"
    }
];

for (var i = e.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (e[i].firstName == "Anna") {
        console.log(e[key]['firstName'] + ', ' + e[key]['lastName']);
        break;
    }
};
```

You need to loop through the Object And find the value for the key you are looking for.
http://jsfiddle.net/mjs2avag/

Comment: Don't use the `for in` syntax with arrays, it's meant to iterate object properties.

Comment: There is no reason to believe that this type of for loop is for Arrays only. The only difference is that the for loop will capture the item prototype.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in - Used to iterate object properties.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar like this

```
var quality = function(obj) {
  if (obj.quality === 'source') {
    return obj;
  }
};

context.download.filter(quality)[0].link;
```

This filter should return each object that matches the filter in a new array.

Answer (score 0):

For more complex queries you can also use a JSON query language such as [JSON Query](https://github.com/mmckegg/json-query) (surprise!)

```
var jsonQuery = require('json-query')

var data = {
  employees: [
    {firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'},
    {firstName: 'Anna', lastName: 'Smith'},
    {firstName: 'Peter', lastName: 'Jones'}
  ]
}

jsonQuery('employees[firstName=Anna].lastName', {
  data: data
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the first array and use a condition to find the value 'anna' , then access it like `employees[i].lastName` . Here is the working example. [JSFIDDLE LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/2ufy6knc/3/)

Html

```js
 var employees = [{
            "firstName": "John",
                "lastName": "Doe"
        }, {
            "firstName": "Anna",
                "lastName": "Smith"
        }, {
            "firstName": "Peter",
                "lastName": "Jones"
        }];
        
       
       for (var i in employees) {
             if (employees[i].firstName == 'Anna') {
                
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = employees[i].lastName;
        
            }
        
        
        
        }
```

```html
 <h3 id="demo"></h3> <!--This one will print smith Anna's lastname -->
```